# Show that $\inf\{t>0: X_t(\omega)\in G\}$ is an optional time.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

> Let $E$ be a finite dimensional Euclidean space. We take $X:=(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ to be an $\Bbb{F}:=(\mathcal{F}_t)_{t\geq 0}$ adapted process with values in $E$. Let $G\subset E$ be open and assume that $X$ has either right- or left-continuous trajectories. Now define $T_{X,G}:=\inf\{t>0: X_t(\omega)\in G\}$. I want to show that this is an $\Bbb{F}$-optional time.

By definition $T$ is an $\Bbb{F}$-optional time if for all $k>0$, $\{T<k\}\in \mathcal{F}_k$. As I understood the part

> assume that $X$ has either right- or left-continuous trajectories

they mean that for a fixed $\omega\in \Omega$, $t\mapsto X_t(\omega)$ is right- or left-continuous.

But now if I fix an arbitrary $k\geq 0$ and consider $$\{T_{X,G}<k\}=\{\inf\{t>0: X_t(\omega)\in G\}<k\}$$ then I don't know how to continue. So I mean if we would work in the discrete case then $\{\inf\{t>0: X_t(\omega)\in G\}<k\}=\bigcup_{1\leq n\leq k-1}\{\inf\{t>0: X_t(\omega)\in G\}=k\}$ but in our case we are not in the discrete one. I think therefore we need this assumption of right- or left-continuous trajectories, but I don't see how this is useful in the proof.

Can maybe someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\inf\{t>0\mid X_t\in G\}<k\iff\exists t\in(0,k),\ X_t\in G,$$
and because $G$ is open and $X_t$ is either left- or right-continuous, the latter is equivalent to
$$
\exists q\in(0,k)\cap\mathbb Q,\ X_q\in G.
$$

Hence
$$
\{T_{X,G}<k\}=\bigcup_{q\in(0,k)\cap\mathbb Q}\{X_q\in G\}\in\mathcal F_k.
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't get the part where you use right-continuity. Could you maybe explain in detail why we have the intersection of $(0,k)$ and $\mathbb{Q}$? And my second question would be, would it be identical when I use left-continuity?

Comment: Suppose $X_t\in G$. If we have right-continuity (resp left-continuity), as $G$ is open there exists $q\in\mathbb Q\cap(t,k)$ (resp. $q\in\mathbb Q\in(0,t))$ such that $X_q\in G$.

Comment: But doesn't right continuity mean that $t\mapsto X_t$ is right continuous?

Comment: Yes. What does it mean for you to be right-continuous, if not my comment just above?

Comment: In my opinion $\phi:t\mapsto X_t$ is right continuous if $\lim_{k\rightarrow t+}\phi(k)$ exists for all $t$, no?

Comment: Yes, and the limit equals $\phi(t)$. So $\lim_{q\to t+}X_q=X_t\in G$. As $G$ is open, this implies that $X_q\in G$ for any $q>t$ close enough from $t$.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, and why do we get at the end that $\bigcup_{q\in(0,k)\cap\mathbb Q}\{X_q\in G\}\in\mathcal F_k$? Is it true that it is because $\{X_q\in G\}=X_q^{-1}(G)\in \mathcal{F}_q\subset \mathcal{F}_k$

Comment: Yes, this is the reason why.